# Updating current record in C# and Access doesn't work

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I have a form where if the user types the correct answer to a hidden question in a textbox, it will go onto the next randomly chosen record in the database, and add +1 to playerscore column in players table of a database. However, the score isn't updated, neither in the database or in the label.

I have cut out all of the other code from this post, such as connection strings but it's there and the connection is being established.

```
    private void SubmitAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int score = 0;

        if (WordBox.Text == WordLbl.Text)
        {
            TopLbl.Text = "Well done! :)";
            synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Well done. Now try answering this...");
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OliveDrab;

            String command = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Questions ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*ID)*Time())";

            try
            {
                FillDataTable(command);
                ShowRow(currentRow);

                score++; // Adding one each time the player spells the word correctly.
                ScoreLabel.Text = "Score: " + score.ToString(); // Update the label to display new score.
                myAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Questions SET players = playerscore + 1 WHERE ID =" + currentRow;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Answer the question" + WordLbl.Text); 
        }

        else
        {
            TopLbl.Text = "Try answering this question again";
            synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Try answering this question again");
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; color on the form.
        }
    }
```

I suspect this is maybe down to `currentRow`. At the top of the program:

`// Index of the current record
        private int currentRow = 0;`

ShowRow class

```
    private void DisplayRow(int rowIndex)
    {
        if (myDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        return; 

        if (rowIndex >= myDataTable.Rows.Count)
        return; 

        try
        {
            DataRow row = myDataTable.Rows[rowIndex];
            KS1WordLbl.Text = row["Word"].ToString();
            synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Answer the question" + WordLbl.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in DisplayRow : \r\n" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nothing. No errors, no warnings.

Comment: erm .SelectCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE ...." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `myDataTable` is populated by FillDataTable and its in scope you should be able to upate your where clause to

```
where id = " + myDataTable.Rows[0].[id].ToString()
```

what you're currently trying to do is more like an in place update and what you need to do is extract the record Id and use that to tell the db what record to update

please note that while you don't have to worry about a SQL injection attack here because the id isn't controlled by the user you should take a look at parameterized queries.

Comment: It is populated by FillDataTable, yes. In `displayRow` class which takes the currentRecord integer, I have something like this wrapped inside a `try`: `DataRow row = myDataTable.Rows[rowIndex];`.

Comment: As far as I can tell the scope of the `row` variable is in the try block. So its not going to help you with your update string